# What kind of instructions and/or case causing the pipeline flushed?

Tags: lua, instructions

We all know that the branch maybe flush the instruct pipeline, how about the function call especially in case from a pointer ?

This question go to my head when I read the part of VM from Lua source code, and did not found something like function lookup table to exectute the instructs instead of using if-cond. Although it's on level difference of instruct execution, why not designs the VM using function lookup table ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Instruction pipelines aren't used in interpreters, they're used in CPU hardware. What do you mean about a function lookup table?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, I just want to know in CPU hardware. Sorry mentioning the interpreter to explaining why I asked this. A function lookup table means way of calling a function via indexing a function-pointer-array.